# Why event.keyCode returns always 65 even if i type 'a' or 'A'?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read keyboard pressed on a website with vanilla javascript. Even if I type 'a' or 'A' the keycode is the same. Is there a way to get not the key pressed but the letter typed. Or maybe, ... the right way to get upper or lowercase is really to get the shiftKey value?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload = function (e) {
                window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({
                        lastKey: {
                            shiftKey: event.shiftKey,
                            code: event.keyCode,
                            char: String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode),
                        }
                    }))
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press 'a':

```
{"lastKey":{"shiftKey":false,"code":65,"char":"A"}}
```

When I press 'shift':

```
{"lastKey":{"shiftKey":true,"code":16,"char":"\u0010"}}
```

When I press 'a with shift':

```
{"lastKey":{"shiftKey":true,"code":65,"char":"A"}}
```

Comment: `keyCode` shows you the actual *keyboard* key that was pressed, it's not the character code.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is not a code for the character the hit key produces, it's a code for the hit key itself. Use [`e.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead, if you need the actual character.

Comment: A simple log and inspection of whole event object would have probably helped you sort this out yourself

Comment: @Antonio Nope, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Comment: @Teemu Ah! It's `event.key`. I was confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `event.key`:

```js
foo.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log(event.key);
})
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
```